# Function name aliasing

Tags: c++, c, function, alias

I have a library that calls a function: eg malloc.
I use the library in my application. I want that the library do not call malloc but a function that i have defined "mymalloc" everytime the malloc is invoked.
In short i want resolve the malloc symbol using a my symbol with a different name.

I have tried this linker option: -Wl,--defsym=malloc=mymalloc

And it works but just for the calls that are in the application
ie: every call to malloc in the program resolves to mymalloc, but the calls in the library still calls to the stdlibc malloc.

Thanks a lot,
Davide

Comment: The feasibility depends on if it's a compiled library or a header-only library. What is it?

Comment: Why can't you just call your function `malloc`? Or write a `malloc` that delegates to `mymalloc`? You may also need to replace `calloc`, `realloc`, `memalign` and `free` (according to https://sourceware.org/ml/libc-help/2012-04/msg00060.html)

Comment: Try looking into the implementation of your `malloc` library. Some libraries allow you to hook into memoery allocations and provide your own custom allocator. If yours supports this you can get the results you want without any hackery in the linker. : http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc_hook

Answer (score 0):

This is crude but you could use the preprocessor - the advantage being that the preprocessor runs prior to compilation:

`#define malloc mymalloc`

You would have to `#include` the file containing the declaration of `mymalloc` *before* any standard library includes.

You would also have to rebuild any compiled libraries yourself. In reality I'd advise doing this in production: I think the code will be brittle and you have the potential of mismatched `mallocs` lurking round every corner.

Comment: You probably want to say "In reality I'd advise **against** doing this in production"